# CS50x - PSET2- Substitution

Tags: c, cs50

I am having troubles with this submission, I don't see a problem with my code and it works fine when I test it but for some reason I don't know when I use check50, it returns this result:

```
:) substitution.c exists
:) substitution.c compiles
:( encrypts "A" as "Z" using ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA as key
Cause
output not valid ASCII text
:( encrypts "a" as "z" using ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA as key
Cause
output not valid ASCII text
:( encrypts "ABC" as "NJQ" using NJQSUYBRXMOPFTHZVAWCGILKED as key
Cause
expected "ciphertext: NJ...", not ""
:( encrypts "XyZ" as "KeD" using NJQSUYBRXMOPFTHZVAWCGILKED as key
Cause
expected "ciphertext: Ke...", not ""
:( encrypts "This is CS50" as "Cbah ah KH50" using YUKFRNLBAVMWZTEOGXHCIPJSQD as key
Cause
expected "ciphertext: Cb...", not ""
:) encrypts "This is CS50" as "Cbah ah KH50" using yukfrnlbavmwzteogxhcipjsqd as key
:( encrypts "This is CS50" as "Cbah ah KH50" using YUKFRNLBAVMWZteogxhcipjsqd as key
Cause
expected "ciphertext: Cb...", not ""
:( encrypts all alphabetic characters using DWUSXNPQKEGCZFJBTLYROHIAVM as key
Cause
expected "ciphertext: Rq...", not ""
:) handles lack of key
:) handles invalid key length
:) handles invalid characters in key
:) handles duplicate characters in key
:) handles multiple duplicate characters in key
```

This results mean that my code outputs the wrong result but when I test the keys and input text myself , it works as it is supposed to, I spent hours trying to figure it out but I am clueless here is my code :

```
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <math.h>

    bool contains(char c, char arr[], int n)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ;i < n; i++)
        {
        if(c == arr[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; 
    }

    bool validkey(string key)
    {
    if (strlen(key) != 26 )
    {
        return false;
    }
    char l[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(key[i]))
        {
            if(contains(key[i],l,i))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                l[i] = key[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

    }

    void cypher(string key, string s)
    {
    int n = strlen(s);

    char r[n+1];
    char t;
    char a = 'a';
    int pos = 0;
    char w;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        if(isalpha(s[i])){
            t = tolower(s[i]);
            pos = t - a;
            if (islower(s[i]))
            {
                r[i]= tolower(key[pos]);

            }
            else if (isupper(s[i]))
            {
                r[i] = toupper(key[pos]);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            r[i] = s[i];

        }
    }
    r[n]='\0';
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n",r);
    }


    int main(int argc, string argv[])
    {
    if(argc != 2)
    {
     return 1;
    }
    string key = argv[1];
    if(!validkey(key))
    {
        printf("Invalid");
        return 1;
    }
    string q = get_string("plain text: ");
    cypher(key,q);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Note, that your `isalpha` check is redundant because `islower` and `isupper` return `true` for alphabetical characters only. Thats is `isalpha(x)` is equivalent to `isupper(x) || islower(x)`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Technically that's only guaranteed in the C locale.

Comment: @dxiv Right. But I think it worth to take this assumption to simplify this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual problem looks to be the fact that you have overlooked the simple output required if no-input is provided, or if an invalid key is provided, e.g. from [Pset2 - Substitution](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/2/substitution/#:%7E:text=f)

And what if a user doesn’t provide a valid key?

```
$ ./substitution ABC
Key must contain 26 characters.
```

Or really doesn’t cooperate?

```
$ ./substitution
Usage: ./substitution key
```

You fail to provide the correct output in each circumstance.

Now your code is a bit rough as pointed out by [@EugeneSh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253229/eugene-sh) in the comments. Your `contains()` is a bit awkward and superfluous. What you need instead is a simple frequency-array. An array of 26-integers, initialized all zero, where you map the characters in key from 0-25 (by converting the char `tolower()` and subtracting `'a'` so `a-z` maps to `0-25`. Then for each character in `key`, you simply check if `array[tolower(key[i]) - 'a']` then it is a duplicate char and return `false`. If not, increment that element and check the next char, e.g.:

```
#define KEYSZ 26

bool validkey (string key)
{
    int keychk[KEYSZ] = {0};
    
    if (strlen (key) != KEYSZ) {
        return false;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; key[i]; i++) {
        int lowerk = tolower(key[i]) - 'a';
        
        if (!isalpha (key[i]) || keychk[lowerk])
            return false;
        
        keychk[lowerk]++;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Where the `keychk[]` array is used for that purpose.

Your `cypher()` function should really return type `string` so the cipher text is available to the calling function, not simply output. (that isn't an error, just a practical consideration). You can rewrite and simplify your `cypher()` function (renamed: `encipher()`) as:

```
string encipher (string key, string s, string cipher)
{
    int i = 0;
    
    for (; s[i]; i++) {
        if (isalpha (s[i])) {
            int pos = tolower (s[i]) - 'a';
            cipher[i] = islower(s[i]) ? tolower(key[pos]) : toupper(key[pos]);
        }
        else
            cipher[i] = s[i];
    }
    cipher[i] = 0;
    
    return cipher;
}
```

Those are really the only two functions needed. If you put it altogether you would have:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define KEYSZ 26

bool validkey (string key)
{
    int keychk[KEYSZ] = {0};
    
    if (strlen (key) != KEYSZ) {
        return false;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; key[i]; i++) {
        int lowerk = tolower(key[i]) - 'a';
        
        if (!isalpha (key[i]) || keychk[lowerk])
            return false;
        
        keychk[lowerk]++;
    }
    
    return true;
}

string encipher (string key, string s, string cipher)
{
    int i = 0;
    
    for (; s[i]; i++) {
        if (isalpha (s[i])) {
            int pos = tolower (s[i]) - 'a';
            cipher[i] = islower(s[i]) ? tolower(key[pos]) : toupper(key[pos]);
        }
        else
            cipher[i] = s[i];
    }
    cipher[i] = 0;
    
    return cipher;
}

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fputs ("Usage: ./substitution key\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    size_t len = 0;
    string key = argv[1];

    if (!validkey (key)) {
        fputs ("Key must contain 26 characters.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    string plain = get_string ("plaintext:  "), cipher;

    len = strlen (plain);
    cipher = malloc (len + 1);

    printf ("ciphertext: %s\n", encipher (key, plain, cipher));

    free (cipher);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** `main()` updated to allocate separately for `cipher` allocating for the number of characters in `plain` (`+1` for the *nul-terminating* character) and changed output prompts, e.g. `"plaintext  "` and `"ciphertext: "` as per the problem, and added `#include <stdlib.h>` which is not included by default with the online `ide.cs50.io` CS50 IDE)

Give that a try and let me know if you have problems or need additional help.

Comment: I tried it and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for the help and I will definitely consider your comments.

Comment: Glad it helped! Let me know if you have any additional questions. Good luck with your coding !